# iOS - Audio level metering of app's audio output

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, audio

I want to show audio meter levels in my app from the audio that my app send to the speaker. I can find the audio level from AVAudioPlayer but it works on audio files.

I have tried to acheive this using **[The Amazing Audio Engine](http://theamazingaudioengine.com/)** as it is provided in its documentation [here](http://theamazingaudioengine.com/doc/_receiving-_audio.html) but I am unable to find out how to do that.

Is it possible to achieve this in ios? Can anyone suggest me any library, audio engine or method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why dont you want to use the AVAudioPlayer? Aren't you playing audio files?

Comment: Currently I want to record a video of an animation based on the audio level meters. I am using Everyplay sdk for this. But when I record video using Everyplay sdk, AVAudioPlayer's audio metering stops working. So I just want the audio recorded(AVAudioPlayer's audio) to the video and obtain audio metering levels info using some alternate method. It is very complex to explain and understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using "remote i/o audio unit for handling audio input and output" this is a possibility:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/aurioTouch2/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html

"… , and a sonogram view (a view displaying the frequency content of a signal over time, with the color signaling relative power, the y axis being frequency and the x as time). Tap the sonogram button to switch to a sonogram view, tap anywhere on the screen to return to the oscilloscope. Tap the FFT button to perform and display the input data after an FFT transform. Pinch in the oscilloscope view to expand and contract the scale for the x axis." …